# Get activate notification in flutter with FCM

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a flutter social network app with firebase
I want to send notification  to user when they get follow,like,comment or any activity
I know firebase cloud massaging do this but how
I want the exact code for this or some thing near with it

Comment: See Firebase documentation for FCM: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/client.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can archive in 2 ways but in both ways you required user's fcm_token or device_token and firebase Server key.

Use this API - `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` to send push notifications to specific users.

1. **If you have own server**

Manage via own server (***secure & most preferred***)

Crate your own API for send notifications to specific user. From your backend get that user's fcm-token & fire actual push API from your server.(firebase server key not save on mobile platform)

Do not include the server key anywhere in your client code. Also, make sure to use only server keys to authorize your app server.

2. **If you don't have own server**.

You need to add firebase sever_key in front-end means app code. (***Less preferable***)

Just call actual firebase push API from your app code.

**Note:** in both ways you required receiver **fcm_token** or **device_token**. Because you need to pass firebase **server_key** & this **token** in that API.

Reference links

1.official latest documentation for API [link1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/send-multiple)

2. Another reference [link2](https://www.fcodelabs.com/2020/04/20/Firebase-Push-Notifications-via-Postman/)
3. API official doc - [link3](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support)

Comment: "Important: Do not include the server key anywhere in your client code. Also, make sure to use only server keys to authorize your app server." https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options